# Spring-test cannot set @RequestPart. It always send it as null

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-test, mockmvc

I cannot test Controller by using `mockMvc` in `spring-test`. I want to know right way to test API with `@RequestPart`.

The method to test is this.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Object> replaceFile(
        @RequestPart("files") Map<String, Object> files,
        @RequestPart("fileKey") String fileKey)
```

And to test I build a mock request like below.

```
    MockMultipartFile blob = new MockMultipartFile("files", files.getBytes());
    MockMultipartFile key = new MockMultipartFile("fileKey", fileKey.getBytes());

    mockMvc.perform(fileUpload("/")
            .file(blob)
            .file(key))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

As you can see, I used `fileUpload`. But in past time, I tried to use `post` with `content` or `requestAttr` because all of them didn't work.

I think current code is the closest to answer among I tried, but can't get closer anymore.

The weird thing is, the real in-use API is almost same with them.
In client side, user sent a new FormData() object to request and server can get data properly.

The server side code is below.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/{variable}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Object> apiMethod(
        @PathVariable int variable,
        @RequestPart("dto1") DTO1 dto1,
        @RequestPart("dto2") DTO2 dto2,
        @RequestPart("file") Map<String, Object> file)
```

"file" part consists of "file name" key and its blob value encoded base64.

For example, `{"hello.txt": "SGVsbG8gd29ybGQh"}`

- What I want to know - Right way to test API with `@RequestPart`
- What I tried

  - method - `fileUpload` / data - `file`, `content`, `requestAttr` but they send `null`.
  - method - `post` / data - `file`, `content`, `requestAttr` but they throw MultipartException.
- Restriction - Cannot use `multipart` because the system is using a low version of Spring.

[image: post]

[image: fileUpload]

Thanks!

Comment: try to use another constructor in test for example: `new MockMultipartFile("fileKey", "filename.txt", "text/plain", "someString".getBytes());`

Comment: @borino 
Thanks a lot! It caused from content type. I missed they are all `application/json`.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @borino who commented to my question, I got the clue of problem.

It is certain to use `fileUpload` for testing API with `@RequestPart` arguments.

In that case,  it caused from content type.
I declared `MockMultipartFile` without `contentType`.

```
MockMultipartFile blob = new MockMultipartFile("files", files.getBytes());
MockMultipartFile key = new MockMultipartFile("fileKey", fileKey.getBytes());
```

But the arguments of API have a type, `Map<String,Object>` and `String` each.
As @borino said to me, I changed constructor of `MockMultipartFile` to make sure `contentType`, and it works!

```
    MockMultipartFile blob = new MockMultipartFile("files", "", "application/json", files.getBytes());
    MockMultipartFile key = new MockMultipartFile("fileKey", "", "application/json", fileKey.getBytes());
```

Just add `contentType` when you have a problem like me. Thanks!